# how to save everything in the webbrowser as Image

Tags: delphi, browser

I would like to save the content of a webbrowser as image. is that possible?

the purpose is to create a screenshot of a page and then viewed it to other application as images.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an [article](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/wb_scren_shot.htm) which provides an example:

```
uses ActiveX;

 procedure WebBrowserScreenShot(const wb: TWebBrowser; const fileName: TFileName) ;
 var
   viewObject : IViewObject;
   r : TRect;
   bitmap : TBitmap;
 begin
   if wb.Document <> nil then
   begin
     wb.Document.QueryInterface(IViewObject, viewObject) ;
     if Assigned(viewObject) then
     try
       bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
       try
         r := Rect(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height) ;

         bitmap.Height := wb.Height;
         bitmap.Width := wb.Width;

         viewObject.Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1, nil, nil, Application.Handle, bitmap.Canvas.Handle, @r, nil, nil, 0) ;

         with TJPEGImage.Create do
         try
           Assign(bitmap) ;
           SaveToFile(fileName) ;
         finally
           Free;
         end;
       finally
         bitmap.Free;
       end;
     finally
       viewObject._Release;
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

and use like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject) ;
 begin
   WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://delphi.about.com') ;
 end;

 procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1NavigateComplete2(ASender: TObject; const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL: OleVariant) ;
 begin
   WebBrowserScreenShot(WebBrowser1,'c:\WebBrowserImage.jpg') ;
 end;
```

Comment: I came across this code in looking for a solution in terms of capturing a screenshot from the webbrowser component. However, all I get is a black image. Using Delphi 10.1 Berlin in Windows 10.